# Release NSObject and stop all method calling

Tags: iphone

So my menu calls a game with this piece of code:

```
game = [[Game alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:memoryTest animated:FALSE];
```

A UIViewController then appears with a countdown. The player can go back to the menu DURING the countdown. However when I try this, the countdown keeps running and eventually the game starts, even thought the UIViewController has been dismissed (therefore the UIView has disappeared) in the backToMenu method.

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];
```

I've tried to release the game object in the viewDidAppear method of the menu, but no luck. I thought of having a "quit" BOOL value, so the countdown can check wether or not the player has quit the game, but there must be a better way to release an object AND stop all method calls inside it.

Thanks for helping me out.

CountDown method:

```
- (void)countDown {

    SoundEffect *sound = [[SoundEffect alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tick" ofType: @"wav"]];
    [sound playAndRelease];

    if(self.countDownStep > 0) {
        feedback.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"countdown%d.png",self.countDownStep]];
        feedback.hidden = FALSE;

        [self performSelector:@selector(countDown) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];
    }

    else {
        [self displayMessage:self.startMessage];
        [self.game performSelector:@selector(start) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];
        [self performSelector:@selector(hide) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];
    }

    self.countDownStep--;

}
```

Comment: Cocoa uses YES/NO instead of False/True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the viewcontroller's viewWillDisappear, check if the timer is running. If it is, then just invalidate it.

[timerObject invalidate] will stop the timer

Answer (score 0):

How do you handle the countdown?  It seems like you want to explicitly void that countdown in the viewWillDisappear method for the UIViewController you mentioned.

Comment: By void I guess you mean "stop it"? How would you do that, other than with a variable comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I was assuming you would use something like NSTimer.  In fact, that might still not be a bad idea.  NSTimer can handle re-running your countdown method every 0.8 seconds.  If you decrement the value to 0, your countdown has expired.  If your view disappears, invalidate the timer in viewWillDisappear.